# Leaflet routing machine with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, leaflet

I am trying to display the route between two points in Next.js 13 using leaflet and the leaflet routing machine as the routing library. I don't know how to get the leaflet-routing-machine to work. I've tried creating functions but I'm so lost. Nothing seems to work  Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import { GoogleMap, InfoWindowF, MarkerF, useJsApiLoader, LoadScript} from '@react-google-maps/api'
import bus from '../public/bus.jpg'
import { createControlComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Switch } from '@headlessui/react';
import bus1 from '../public/bus.jpg'
import L, { Routing, map } from "leaflet";
import {
  LayersControl
} from "react-leaflet";



const containerStyle = {
  width: '80%',
  height: '100%'
};

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};  

const busStops: string[] = [
  "ATM/ LIBRARY",
  "ADMIN",
  "MURNI",
  "BW",
  "AMANAH",
  "DSS",
  "ILMU",
  "COE",
];


const maps = {
  base: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
};


function route () {

  const map = useMap;
 
   
};


export default function Home() {

    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [start, setStart] = useState([38.9072, -77.0369])
  const [end, setEnd] = useState([37.7749, -122.4194])
  const [show, setShow] = useState (false);

  
  
  return (

    
    <div className='w-screen bg-red-500 h-screen flex'>


      
      <div className='w-[400px] bg-white flex flex-col '>
    <div className='w-full h-[80px]  flex justify-center items-center'>
      <h1 className=' text-black'>Route Infomation</h1>
    </div>
    <div className=' h-full bg-white justify-center items-center flex flex-col p-10 space-y-12'>

    <div className=' w-full bg-white  text-black text-center'>Uniten Library</div>
    <div className=' w-full bg-white  text-black text-center'>Uniten Admin</div>
    <div className=' w-full bg-white  text-black text-center'>Cendekiawan</div>
    <div className=' w-full bg-white  text-black text-center'>Murni</div>
    <div className=' w-full bg-white  text-black text-center'>Amanah</div>

    </div>
      </div>


      <MapContainer center={[2.976644517019155, 101.73402673751899]} zoom={30} scrollWheelZoom={true} className=' w-full h-full z-10'>
<TileLayer
  attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"

  


/>


<Marker position={[2.9776400979295072, 101.73074640990319]}>
    <Popup>
      UNITEN Admin Building<br />
    </Popup>
  </Marker>


  <Marker position={[2.976644517019155, 101.73402673751899]}> 
    <Popup >
      <div className='w-[300px] h-[400px] flex flex-col rounded-lg'>
        <div className=' h-1/3 w-full bg-white ease-in-out'> <Image className='rounded-xl h-full' src={bus} alt='/'/> </div>
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center px-5'>
        <div className=''> Uniten Library</div>
        <p>ETA</p>
        <p>Arrival Status</p>
        </div>
        
        <div className='flex'>
        <div className=' h-1/3 w-full p-5'>Driver 1 </div>
        <div className=' h-1/3 w-full p-5'>ETA: 7:45 AM</div>
        <Switch
        checked={show}
        onChange={setShow}
        className={`${show ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-gray-700'}
          relative inline-flex h-[28px] w-[64px] shrink-0 cursor-pointer rounded-full border-2 border-transparent transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75`}
      >
        <span className="sr-only">Use setting</span>
        <span
          aria-hidden="true"
          className={`${show ? 'translate-x-9' : 'translate-x-0'}
            pointer-events-none inline-block h-[24px] w-[24px] transform rounded-full bg-white shadow-lg ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out`}
        />
      </Switch>

        </div>
        

      

      </div>
    </Popup>
  </Marker>



<div>
</div>


    {/* <Routing /> */}

</MapContainer>



    </div>
  )
}
```